# Hubot-Cleverbot script issue heirarchy

Tags: javascript, hubot

I'm using a cleverbot script to have my bot respond to any type of messages.  The script works but currently requires a user to call for the bot via "hey"

For example

```
"@bot hey what is going on?"
bot: Not too much.
```

Code:

```
robot.respond(/hey (.*)/i, function(msg) {
//code for reply
}
```

What I want to do is have it so I can just ask the question directly to my bot without requiring the "hey" part.  I originally got rid of the "hey" tag but it interferes with my other scripts that are set to respond to certain text.  In other words, I get two responses from my bot.

Any ideas on how to tell my cleverbot script to only respond if all the other scripts have been confirmed first?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `@robot.catchAll`. A CatchAll listener will execute iff no other regex matched the message, but know that means it *won't* execute if you have any scripts that match all messages (e.g. `robot.hear /.*/`).

Some documentation (part of a separate PR waiting to be merged, so ignore `catchAllAddressed`) -- https://github.com/michaelansel/hubot/blob/issues/683/docs/scripting.md#catch-all